can't get proper context.selected_ids from 3d view
I'm trying to get selected objects from outliner running an operator from 3d view.
In outliner 2 objects selected (one hided: 'eye' disabled). Running an operator from any other area (Text editor, Properties, Node editor) withing F3, get proper selection, but not from 3d view. What I'm doing wrong?
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # Get the largest outliner area and its region
        largest_area = None
        largest_region = None
        max_size = 0
        
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
                # Calculate the area size
                width = area.width
                height = area.height
                size = width * height
                
                if size > max_size:
                    max_size = size
                    largest_area = area

        if largest_area:
            # Find the region of the largest outliner area
            for region in largest_area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':  # We want the main window region
                    largest_region = region
                    break
        
        if largest_area and largest_region:
            # Create an override context for the largest area and region
            override_context = context.copy()
            override_context['area'] = largest_area
            override_context['region'] = largest_region
            
            with context.temp_override(**override_context):
                selection = context.selected_ids
                selected = [sel for sel in selection if sel.rna_type.name != 'Collection']
                print(selected)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


get_selected_ids(area)
A function to get selected_ids from a specific area,
raise error when input a wrong area

Parameters:
area (bpy.types.Area)

Returns:
None or sequence of bpy.types.ID



import bpy

class GetSelectedIDs(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.get_selected_ids"
    bl_label = "Get Selected IDs"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    selected_ids = None

    def execute(self, context):
        GetSelectedIDs.selected_ids = context.selected_ids
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(GetSelectedIDs)

def get_selected_ids(area):
    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
        bpy.ops.wm.get_selected_ids("INVOKE_REGION_WIN") # require INVOKE_REGION_WIN

    return GetSelectedIDs.selected_ids

    

# Get the largest outliner area and its region
largest_area = None

max_size = 0

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        # Calculate the area size
        width = area.width
        height = area.height
        size = width * height
        
        if size > max_size:
            max_size = size
            largest_area = area

if largest_area:
    ids = get_selected_ids(largest_area)
    
    print(ids)
else:
    print("Area not found")


Don't copy the entire context.
IMO threading on XY problem (aptly named after the person who first responded to this Q&A ><) here because the whole finding largest area has nothing to do with the actual problem.
TLDR replace override_context = context.copy() with override_context = {}
Back to the original script :
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):        
        largest_area = (max((a for a in context.screen.areas if a.type == "OUTLINER"), key=lambda a:a.width * a.height))
        largest_region = next(r for r in largest_area.regions if r.type == "WINDOW")

        if largest_area and largest_region:
            override_context = {
                'area': largest_area,
                'region': largest_region
            }
            
            with context.temp_override(**override_context):
                print([sel for sel in context.selected_ids if sel.rna_type.name != 'Collection'])

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thanks! That a little thing with {} ... nice! If I change 'accept answer', will it be rude to the participant in the discussion? :)
